# getting over-tested in review session

Tags: feature-request, support, review, review-abuse

I've just had a go at reviewing... Got a completely stupid answer, flagged it, was congratulated... Then I got another test. Another. Another. I did about 15 reviews; there was one genuine question.

Sorry but - I'm fed up. I've read the posts on abusing reviews. I know that's why the tests exists. But I've never sped through reviewing. When reading an answer, I often follow up the question to see what other answers there were, and a lot of other work. I feel treated like some kind of serial offender.

This may be asking for support, or for a feature. Is there something that triggers those tests? I tend to flag and comment rather than downvote, would a pattern like that cause suspicion?

And the feature: if some passes review testing again, and again, and again, could there be some mechanism to make sure that they move on to genuine reviewing?

Comment: Your righteous indignation is premature.

Comment: I've just had a go at participating on Meta... Saw a duplicate answer to an existing bug report, so I voted to close it as such, and others agreed... Then I saw another posted. Another, Another. I closed about 5 dupes, there was one genuine non-dupe question. Sorry but - I'm fed up. (etc.).

Comment: @MartijnPieters sorry, I looked for something like this, I thought I couldn't have been the only one but couldn't find the previous question. Will remove - in two days, as apparently must wait.

Comment: @boisvert: Don't worry; I was just pulling your leg there. The question page does link a swathe of duplicate questions, all closed already, though.

Comment: It's a bug, **please** come back later and help us review. This is the first time this has happened, and we are going to need all the help we can get when it gets cleared up.